# How to solve google security alert - less secure encryption mode

Tags: android, security, kotlin, encryption

Below is my code, its encryption is less secure, alert from google playstore. pointing to encrypt method inside encrypter.kt file. can anybody help to get rid of this alert.I have only less knowledge in encryption technic.

```
**Encryptor.kt**
```

internal class Encryptor {

```
private var iv: ByteArray? = null

@Throws(UnrecoverableEntryException::class, NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, KeyStoreException::class, NoSuchProviderException::class, NoSuchPaddingException::class, InvalidKeyException::class, IOException::class, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException::class, SignatureException::class, BadPaddingException::class, IllegalBlockSizeException::class)

fun encryptText(alias: String, textToEncrypt: String): ByteArray? {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias))

        iv = cipher.iv
        return cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    }
    else{
        return encrypt(alias,textToEncrypt)
    }
}

@Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, NoSuchProviderException::class, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException::class)

private fun getSecretKey(alias: String): SecretKey {

    val keyGenerator: KeyGenerator

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE)

        keyGenerator.init(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .build())
    } else {
        // or something like

        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", ANDROID_KEY_STORE)

        // use the supported init method here such as this one: https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html#init(int, java.security.SecureRandom)
        keyGenerator.init(256)
    }

    return keyGenerator.generateKey()
}

fun getIv():ByteArray? {
    return iv
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
fun encrypt(seed: String, cleartext: String): ByteArray {
    iv = getivNew(seed.toByteArray())
    return encrypt(iv!!, cleartext.toByteArray())
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
private fun encrypt(raw: ByteArray, clear: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)
    val encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear)
    return encrypted
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
private fun getivNew(seed: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    val md5Bytes = md.digest(seed) // 128 Bit = 16 byte SecretKey
    val skey = SecretKeySpec(md5Bytes, "AES")
    return skey.getEncoded()
}

companion object {

    private const val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
    private const val ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore"
}
```

}

**Decryptor.kt**

internal class Decryptor @Throws(CertificateException::class, NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, KeyStoreException::class, IOException::class)

constructor() {

```
private var keyStore: KeyStore? = null

init {
    initKeyStore()
}

@Throws(KeyStoreException::class, CertificateException::class, NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, IOException::class)
private fun initKeyStore() {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
    keyStore?.load(null)
}

@Throws(UnrecoverableEntryException::class, NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, KeyStoreException::class, NoSuchProviderException::class, NoSuchPaddingException::class, InvalidKeyException::class, IOException::class, BadPaddingException::class, IllegalBlockSizeException::class, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException::class)

fun decryptData(alias: String, encryptedData: ByteArray, encryptionIv: ByteArray): String {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, encryptionIv)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias), spec)

        return String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData), Charsets.UTF_8)
    }
    else{
        return decrypt(encryptionIv,encryptedData)
    }
}

@Throws(NoSuchAlgorithmException::class, UnrecoverableEntryException::class, KeyStoreException::class)

private fun getSecretKey(alias: String): SecretKey {
    return (keyStore?.getEntry(alias, null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry).secretKey
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
private fun decrypt(raw: ByteArray, encrypted: ByteArray): String {
    val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)
    val decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted)
    return String(decrypted)
}

companion object {

    private const val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
    private const val ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore"
}
```

}

**SimpleCrypto.kt**

object SimpleCrypto {

```
private val HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF"

@Throws(Exception::class)
fun decryptNew(seed: String, encrypted: String): String {
    val rawKey = getRawKeyNew(seed.toByteArray())
    val enc = toByte(encrypted)
    val result = decrypt(rawKey, enc)
    return String(result)
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
private fun getRawKeyNew(seed: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    val md5Bytes = md.digest(seed) // 128 Bit = 16 byte SecretKey
    val skey = SecretKeySpec(md5Bytes, "AES")
    return skey.getEncoded()
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
private fun decrypt(raw: ByteArray, encrypted: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    val skeySpec = SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec)
    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted)
}

fun toByte(hexString: String): ByteArray {
    val len = hexString.length / 2
    val result = ByteArray(len)
    for (i in 0 until len)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2),
                16).toByte()
    return result
}
```

}

Comment: In "encrypt(raw: ByteArray, clear: ByteArray): ByteArray" you instantiate the cipher with "Cipher.getInstance("AES")" and that means the **UNSECURE** AES mode **ECB**. Try to change to "AES/CBC/PKCS5padding" [you need to generate a random initialization vector that gets prepended to the ciphertext similar to AES/GCM-part of your code.

Comment: Hi Michael Fehr, Thanks for your comment: I added this following line in companion object:  private const val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding". if i changed to this "AES/CBC/PKCS5padding" and add TRANSFORMATION instead of "AES" , is it enough to solve this issue